# HTTP client with free(): invalid pointer error while freeing contents of char **

Tags: c, arrays, http, pointers, free

I've looked all over for solutions to this problem but tools like Valgrind and GDB are not helping me. Valgrind doesn't even finish running the program and GDB just tells me information that contradicts itself. I have an HTTP client that allocates a list of strings from the headers retrieved from a web server. When trying to free this allocated list of individually allocated strings, it decides to call `free(): invalid pointer` after I tried fixing the issue of the header-parsing function cutting off the final header. I've been looking at it for hours and I cannot find a single issue.

**To be sure the code works, I've tested it with two main sites: http://www.google.com/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/**. Usually only one works at a time when I fix a memory error on the other example.

Here is where I parse the header string (a string containing `\r\n` between headers and only a terminating null at the end):

```
char **generateHeaderList(char *headers) {
    char **returnHeaders = NULL, *nextLine;
    int len, n;
    for (n = 0; (nextLine = strstr(headers, "\r\n")) != NULL; n++) {
        len = nextLine - headers;
        if (len == 0) break;
        returnHeaders = realloc(returnHeaders, (n + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if (returnHeaders == NULL) {
            printf("Failure to allocate memory at line %d.\r\n", __LINE__ - 2);
            exit(1);
        }
        returnHeaders[n] = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        copyAndTerminateString(returnHeaders[n], headers, len);
        headers = nextLine + 2;
    }
    len = strlen(headers); //here to returnHeaders[n+1] = NULL; is what I've added that's caused this error with some websites
    if (len == 0) return returnHeaders;
    returnHeaders = realloc(returnHeaders, (n + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    if (returnHeaders == NULL) {
        printf("Failure to allocate memory at line %d.\r\n", __LINE__ - 2);
        exit(1);
    }
    returnHeaders[n] = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    copyAndTerminateString(returnHeaders[n], headers, len);
    returnHeaders[n+1] = NULL;
    return returnHeaders;
}
```

Here is how I free the structure containing the data in `returnHeaders`:

```
void freeHTTPresponse(HTTPresponse *freeResponse) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; freeResponse->headers[n] != NULL; n++) {
        free(freeResponse->headers[n]);
    }
    free(freeResponse->headers);
    free(freeResponse->content);
    free(freeResponse);
}
```

Here is the full code (edited to only print out information pertaining to my problem): http://pastebin.com/AWWTLpWH

Comment: when using realloc(),  always save the returned value into a temporary pointer variable, not the target pointer variable.  Then check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful, If == NULL, then handle error  else copy temporary pointer variable into target pointer variable.  The reason for the temporary variable is because if realloc() returns NULL, and saved directly into the target variable, then a memory leak occurs because the pointer to the allocated memory is lost

Comment: you state the code works.  I downloaded the file from pastebin,  tried compiling it.  There are a few dozen problems.   Suggest enabling all the warning and re-compiling.  fix the problems, then repost the code into pastebin.  There is not much we can offer in the way of debug help when the posted code does not compile.

Comment: If realloc() returns NULL, I EXIT_FAILURE and the operating system handles allocated memory from there. I also compile with gcc -Wall to make sure I have no warnings. The program clearly doesn't work, as there is an invalid pointer error. I fixed the error and you can see the code here: http://pastebin.com/35ScGHRR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
returnHeaders[n+1] = NULL;
```

writes past the end of the `returnHeaders` array (which has `n+1` elements).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as I can, but I spent hours chasing after stupid mistakes. Thank you. Logically, it just made sense to get the n+1th item in an array n+1 char pointers long.

Comment: Happens to us all! Also note your comment in the code that you need to set the `n+1` element to null when you return early - you will need to do that as you rely on it later.